# How can I add a title to an horizontal ListView that's inside a SliverToBoxAdapter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SliverToBoxAdapter` containing a `ListView` of `FilterChips`. I want to add a title at the beginning of `ListView` but I'm always getting a `Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width` error.

Here's my code:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          child: ListView.separated(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: _expectedAnswers.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 7, width: 7);
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return FilterChip(
                    label: Text('Hello');
                    // rest of FilterChip params here 
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
```

This code as is works OK. But when I'm trying to add a title in front of the list, I'm getting the error above. Here's my attempt:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Title'),
              ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: _expectedAnswers.length,
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SizedBox(height: 7, width: 7);
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return FilterChip(
                    label: Text('Hello');
                    // rest of FilterChip params here 
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Add `Expanded` widget as parent for the `ListView`

Comment: Thanks. This worked! If you add it as an answer, I will proceed with accepting it.